# Android Studio Activity theme causes crash

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I have spent a long time on forums looking at how to change the theme for my activities in android app development.

My main objective is to remove the title bar. But would still like to know how to change themes in general.

I have tried changing the theme using the GUI built into Android Studio... the theme changes in the preview, but when I run the app on my phone nothing changes.

So I figured I would change the theme using some xml code in the Manifest file.

What everyone seems to be doing is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dennis.activeapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        <!--  HERE IS WHERE I SET THE THEME  -->

        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <activity  
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >    
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />   
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sec" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FirActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fir" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The above is my code.

Now, when I try to run this on my phone the app crashes. The app opens for a fraction of a second and then closes.

If it is any help my phone is the Cubot S208. Since I have a feeling the problem might not be the code, as I followed directly what people have said in previous posts/forums.

The error message I receive in the ADB logs is the following:

```
ddms: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.read(Client.java:731)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:311)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device     0123456789ABCDEF: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on     your device.
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device     0123456789ABCDEF: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on     your device.
```

However I am certain that is the code below the comment (The theme) that is causing this issue. As without it I have no crash !

Comment: Use LogCat to see the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: LogCat provides no information. I have posted the ADB log is that is any help. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: What you did post suggests that your IDE cannot work with your device, and that should be your near-term focus. Until you can reliably examine LogCat, there is little point in continuing development. If your app is crashing, then LogCat definitely will have a stack trace or some other messages.